# Removing from ArrayList Not Working

Tags: powershell, arraylist

The following portion of code is supposed to loop over one array "idleusers," removing these users from an arraylist "finalusers" if they also have a certain application running.

```
$apps = get-process -IncludeUserName |  Sort-Object -Property ID -Unique

foreach ($app in $apps){
    if ($idleusers -contains $app.username) {
        if ($app.path -like 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DirectoryOfTheApplication\*') {
            #if ($app.username -eq 'Domain\UsernameThatDoesNotRemove') {
            #    $finalusers.remove('Domain\UsernameThatDoesNotRemove')
            #}
            $finalusers.remove($app.username)
        }
    }
}

$finalusers
```

This works, and removes most of the desired users, but there are 2 or 3 users left over that did not get removed. The commented-out if loop is one that I used to try and debug. When you un-comment those lines and run the code, it does remove the user. This means that the if statements should be working properly, and the problem is most likely with the remove statement.

**Edit 2**:
Sorry for the poor question, I've been a lurker here for a long time but this is my first shot at participating. I read the help article and tried to narrow down the code. Here it is, the full script, without the functions and without anything that didn't pertain to this error:

```
$quserresult = invoke-expression -Command "quser /SERVER:$serverName" | select -Skip 1       

$users = @()

foreach($row in $quserresult)
{        
    $person = new-object Object
    $columns = $row.Replace("  ", " ").Split(" ") | ? {$_ -ne ""}    

    $person | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name UserName -value $columns[0]           

    $users += $person
}

$idleusers = @()
foreach($usrn in $users){
    $nme = $usrn.UserName
    $idleusers += "Domain\$nme"    
}

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$finalusers = $idleusers

$apps = get-process -IncludeUserName |  Sort-Object -Property ID -Unique

foreach ($app in $apps){
    if ($idleusers -contains $app.username) {
        if ($app.path -like 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DirectoryOfTheApplication\*') {
            #if ($app.username -eq 'Domain\UsernameThatDoesNotRemove') {
            #    $finalusers.remove('Domain\UsernameThatDoesNotRemove')
            #}
            $finalusers.remove($app.username)
        }
    }
}

$finalusers
```

**Final Edit:** Thanks, it was because -contains is not case sensitive. I made sure to format it all in lowercase and now it works.

The final code:

```
$quserresult = invoke-expression -Command "quser /SERVER:$serverName" | select -Skip 1       

$users = @()

foreach($row in $quserresult)
{        
    $person = new-object Object
    $columns = $row.Replace("  ", " ").Split(" ") | ? {$_ -ne ""}    

    $person | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name UserName -value $columns[0]           

    $users += $person
}

$idleusers = @()
foreach($usrn in $users){
    $nme = $usrn.UserName.ToLower()
    $idleusers += "staley\$nme"    
}

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$finalusers = $idleusers

$apps = get-process -IncludeUserName |  Sort-Object -Property ID -Unique

foreach ($app in $apps){
    $appuser = $null
    $appuser = $app.username
    if ($appuser) {
        if ($idleusers -contains $appuser.ToLower()) {
            if ($app.path -like 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DirectoryOfTheApplication\*') {
                $finalusers.remove($appuser.ToLower())
            }
        }
    }
}

$finalusers
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? We can't tell you what's going on with the $finalusers variable because you haven't shown how it's populated.

Comment: It's still difficult to help. It may help you to read the article "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" in the help center. If you suspect the problem is with ArrayList->remove, try to construct a minimal, complete and verifiable example around that.

Comment: Regarding msdn, ArrayList::remove is using Object.Equals to make the lookup. Are you sure **$app.username** has the same case that the strings in **$finalusers**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonathan Muller's comment almost certainly points at your problem.

The comparison `$idleusers -contains $app.username` is not as strict as the comparison used by ArrayList when it tries to remove the `$app.username` element. The former comparison will match "Domain\UserName" with "domain\username", but the latter will not. If you use `-ccontains` instead of `-contains`, that would be case sensitive, but I don't think that will solve your problem, it would only make the comparisons more consistent - it's likely that modifying code in `get-terminal-users` is the correct solution.

However, I'm not able to reproduce the problem because you haven't posted the code for `get-terminal-users`.

Comment: Thanks for you and Jonathan's help, this was the correct answer. I misunderstood the -contains command and thought it was case sensitive.